# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field - Springboot the Application, the component and the test class are all in the same package

Tags: spring-boot

My understanding is that the SpringBootApplication annotation includes
ComponentScan

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

The bean is discovered and printed in Application.main(), why does the unit test not find it?

This unit test fails with:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServicesTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'etlFileServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServices' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

With the appropriate level of debug, i.e "org.springframework.context.annotation"="debug" I can see that the bean was discovered during component scanning.

Nevertheless, the unit test results in:

[ERROR] getAll(com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServicesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServicesTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'etlFileServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServices' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServices' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The Application:

```
package com.pds.pdssr.bootstrap;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

//@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pds.pdsssr.jpa")
@SpringBootApplication
// @EntityScan("com.pds.pdssr.models")
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            logger.info("bean: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

The Component:

package com.pds.pdssr.bootstrap;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.pds.pdssr.models.EtlFile;

@Repository
public class EtlFileServices {

    @Autowired
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("entityManagerFactory is null");
        }
        sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<EtlFile> getAll() {
        return getAll("etlFile",getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected List getAll(String tableName, Session session) {
        String queryText = "from " + tableName;
        return getList(tableName, queryText, session);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected List getList(String tableName, String queryText, Session session) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        Query query = session.createQuery(queryText);
        List result = query.list();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long millis = (end - start) / 1000000;
        //logger.debug("table: " + tableName + " millis " + millis + " rows:  " + result.size());
        return result;
    }


}
```

The test class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.pds.pdssr.bootstrap.EtlFileServices;
import com.pds.pdssr.models.EtlFile;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EtlFileServicesTest {
    @Autowired
    private EtlFileServices etlFileServices;

    @Test 
    public void getAll() {
        List<EtlFile>  etlFiles = etlFileServices.getAll();
        assertNotNull(etlFiles);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happened if you add `@SpringBootTest(classes = HipsterWebApp.class)` after `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation ?

Comment: It gets further, however

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.468 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServicesTest
[ERROR] getAll(com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServicesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.102 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: entityManagerFactory is null
 at com.pds.pdssr.etlfile.EtlFileServicesTest.getAll(EtlFileServicesTest.java:27)

Comment: Why you need to have session factory in your code? Is there any specifics reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer:**

You need to have

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourMainClass.class)
```

in your test class(es).

**Further answer based on comment**

If you really want to have `SessionFactory` in your project, you need to tell spring framework to have SessionContext explicitly. It can be done by add

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class = org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

to your configuration file. [Here's a working example for your problem](https://gitlab.com/xsalefter/pdssr).

HTH